Unity 3D: Door rotation around pivot point not working as expected
I'm trying to create a door that rotates realistically (like opening and closing) in Unity 3D, but I'm encountering some issues:

When I try to rotate the door, it rotates around its center instead of the edge where the hinges should be.
I attempted to fix this by moving the pivot point to the edge of the door in the Transform component, but when I move the door to an empty GameObject, the pivot point resets and aligns with the door's center again.


What I've Tried

Adjusting the pivot point in the Transform component
Moving the door to an empty GameObject to control rotation


have you considered using a hinge?

@BugFinder whats that ? first time i hear it!

Its exactly as it sounds, its a physics hinge which you can set to have bounds so eg a door cant open more than 90 degrees either way, or only outwards, etc..  I had a bunch of issues such as animations where if you tried to use the door differently it seemed to go wonky, and i really did get frustrated - as have you, slap a hinge on, and .. tada..  the hinge decides where the pivot is!!! cos well IT is the hinge :D so you can make 1 door a catflap and another a barn door - have a look on youtube for a tutorial, ive not looked back

@BugFinder I got you , im using rotating door  script to rotate the door to 90 only , without using animator  to make it easier for me as biggener!

The hinge is even simpler, there is zero code :)

@BugFinder im intersting , how ?

as I said, its a hinge.. go look up the tutorial, theres no way I can explaain here

Although the image is a bit dim, I noticed the button on the top left of the scene window, you selected Center, you need to select Pivot.
Also you can check the section "Gizmo handle position toggles" in the document: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html

Yes, I always recommend to keep the Gizmo mode to Pivot and Local and only switch temporarily when you really need it. In almost all cases you want to know the actual position and orientation of an object. When switched to Global, all gizmo handles would be aligned with the world. This can be useful when positioning things while editing, but in all other cases it's confusing / misleading.
